# Пул констант в Java

Tags: java, переменные, jvm, const, константа

Не раз слышал о так называемом пуле констант в языке программирования Java. Знаю о пуле объектов типа `String`, пуле для типов `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer`, `Long` и даже `Boolean`.

Также знаю, что мы сами можем определять размер пула типа `Integer`, если запускать приложение с параметром:

```
Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=XX
```

где XX может колебаться в диапазоне от 127 до (`Integer.MAX_VALUE` - 129).

Весь этот пул представляет собой массив, каждое значение которого является элементом, расположенным в порядке числового возрастания, и мы можем напрямую обратиться к нему по индексу за константное время O(1).

Я прекрасно понимаю, где хранится этот массив. У каждого целочисленного обёрточного типа есть свой вложенный класс такого типа:

```
private static class WrappingСlassNameCache {...}
```

где вместо `WrappingСlassNameCache` мы подставляем конкретное имя класса, к примеру, `IntegerCache`.
Внутри это выглядит так:

```
private static class IntegerCache {
    static final int low = -128;
    static final int high;
    static final Integer cache[];

    static {
        // high value may be configured by property
        int h = 127;
        String integerCacheHighPropValue =
            sun.misc.VM.getSavedProperty("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
        if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
            try {
                int i = parseInt(integerCacheHighPropValue);
                i = Math.max(i, 127);
                // Maximum array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
                h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - (-low) -1);
            } catch( NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // If the property cannot be parsed into an int, ignore it.
            }
        }
        high = h;

        cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
        int j = low;
        for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
            cache[k] = new Integer(j++);

        // range [-128, 127] must be interned (JLS7 5.1.7)
        assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    }
```

Ну Бог с ним, тут ничего мудрёного нет! А что же такое пул констант? Что он из себя представляет? И вообще где хранятся все константы в Java?

Если мы говорим о локальных финализированных переменных, то они хранятся в стековой памяти. Если мы имеем дело со `static final`-полями, то эти поля хранятся в MetaSpace (раньше в PermGen), если мы говорим о реализации JVM HotSpot.

Так о каком вообще пуле может идти речь? Как всё это реализовано? Описано в каком-то классе, который поставляется вместе со стандартным API от Oracle (раньше Sun Microsystems) или же это нужно заглядывать в реализацию конкретной JVM и читать JVMS?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, надоело, что в которой раз сталкиваюсь с этим понятием и никак не могу понять, о чём идёт речь. Всем огромное спасибо за помощь! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

У каждого класса свой пул констант. Чтобы понять для чего он нужен, разберём простой пример

```
class Example {
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Скомпилируем

```
$ javac Example.java
```

И заглянем внутрь

```
$ javap -c -v Example.class

public class Example
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #6.#14         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #15.#16        // java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   #3 = String             #17            // Hello
   #4 = Methodref          #18.#19        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   #5 = Class              #20            // Example
   #6 = Class              #21            // java/lang/Object
   #7 = Utf8               <init>
   #8 = Utf8               ()V
   #9 = Utf8               Code
  #10 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #11 = Utf8               hello
  #12 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #13 = Utf8               Example.java
  #14 = NameAndType        #7:#8          // "<init>":()V
  #15 = Class              #22            // java/lang/System
  #16 = NameAndType        #23:#24        // out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #17 = Utf8               Hello
  #18 = Class              #25            // java/io/PrintStream
  #19 = NameAndType        #26:#27        // println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #20 = Utf8               Example
  #21 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #22 = Utf8               java/lang/System
  #23 = Utf8               out
  #24 = Utf8               Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #25 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
  #26 = Utf8               println
  #27 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
{
  public Example();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0

  public void hello();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: ldc           #3                  // String Hello
         5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
        line 4: 8
}
```

Первое, что представляет интерес - это байткоды метода `hello`:

```
 0: getstatic     #2
 3: ldc           #3
 5: invokevirtual #4
```

Цифры до двоеточия обозначают байт, с которого начинается байткод и его параметры. По шагу видно, что каждая операция - это два байта, один байт на код операции и один байт на параметр. Байткоды могут принимать только параметры фиксированного размера - integer, long, short, byte, character, float, double, **reference**. Чтобы передать в метод `println` строку "Hello", надо загрузить в стек ссылку на строку "Hello", а саму строку где-то сохранить. Вот это где-то как раз и есть пул констант. А символы `#3` после байткода `ldc` - ссылка на 3-й элемент в пуле констант.

```
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #6.#14         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #15.#16        // java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   #3 = String             #17            // Hello
   #4 = Methodref          #18.#19        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Как можно увидеть из этого кусочка пула, его элементы сами часто ссылаются в пул. В частности наша строка под номером 3 ссылается на массив символов под номером 17.

Если говорить о расположении пула констант в памяти JVM, то это один из участков  MetaSpace.

Comment: Отлично объяснили, я очень доволен! Спасибо Вам за это! Моя проблема, насколько я понял, заключалась в самом непонимании сущности констант. Я полагал, что константы в Java, это некоторые значения, которые устанавливаются один раз и не могут меняться на протяжении всего выполнения программы. Но это не совсем так, тут скорее речь идёт о финализированных переменных. Если провести параллель с прародителем Java'ы, языком программирования C++, то выяснится, что те сущности, которые в сообществе программистов C++ принято называть константами, в Java'е не представлены.

Comment: @Lexoid [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Именно поэтому ключевое слово const зарезервировано для возможного использования в будущем, но на текущий момент времени не используется. А теперь самое основное, что я хотел бы у Вас уточнить! Исходя из моего понимания представленного Вами дизассемблированного байт-кода, правильно ли считать константами, абсолютно все сущности, которые не меняют своей формы/значения на протяжении всего промежутка времени исполнения приложения. Значит ли это, что константами, с точки зрения Jav'ы являются все идентификаторы (имена переменных, методов, классов и интерфейсов), а также строковые литералы? Верно?

Comment: А также адреса объектов, которые хранятся в куче. Сами адреса объектов хранятся в ссылочных переменных и являются константами, так как объект, насколько я понимаю, не перемещается по куче и имеет свой постоянный (константный) адрес, который не меняется с течением времени. Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я не прав! Это действительно очень ценная информация, в интернете её не так уж и просто найти. Убеждён, что ответ на данный вопрос будет полезен огромному числу пользователей! Благодарю за понимание!

Comment: Первый комментарий правильный, а второй нет. Объекты постоянно перемещаются, с каждой сборкой мусора.

Comment: И адреса объектов постоянно меняются? То есть, это переменная величина? Что-то новенькое для меня, если честно, то впервые с таким сталкиваюсь. Если меняются их адреса в памяти, то после каждой сборки мусора новые адреса автоматически переприсваиваются ссылочным переменным? Выходит так? То есть, адреса объектов в памяти, которые хранятся в переменных ссылочных типов, не относятся к константам? Благодарю за очередное уточнение! :)

Comment: буду благодарен Вам за ответ!)

Comment: Да, постоянно меняются и переприсваиваются. Тема сборки мусора сложная и обширная.

Comment: Благодарю! Хоть немного удалось разобраться! Спасибо Вам за это! :)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.