# Просмотр java байт кода в текстовом редакторе

Tags: java, байткод

Читая статью в интернете о том что после компиляции java приложения в байт код, его просмотр с помощью текстового редактора уже становится невозможен. 
У меня же при открытии скомпилированных классов почему-то видны некоторые фрагменты программы такие как: Название методов, имена и типы переменных, имена пакетов.

Собственно вопрос, почему?

Comment: Нельзя без дополнительных средств просмотреть код, но [константы сохраняются в class-файлах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/846541/204271), как обычные строки и доступны для просмотра.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно любой нормальный Java IDE умеет на лету декомпилировать объектные коды из .class файлов и подставлять их в просмотровщик. Эту задачу декомпиляции еще облегчает наличие т.н. *debug* (отладочной) информации оставляемой компилятором в объектных кодах (например, номера строк). Еще более задача облегчается когда уже где-то есть исходные тексты - тогда задача становится совсем тривиальной бери из объектного кода номер строки и вставляй вместо нее строку из исходника.

В нормальном, продакшн коде стараются убрать все эти ссылки на названия переменных и методов и применяют обфускацию, когда обфускатор меняет имена переменных на более-менее случайные имена, тем самым запутывая декомпиляцию.